# How to Upload Documents using Visual Fox Pro

Tags: list, splistitem, file-upload, sharepoint-library

We have an application written in foxpro, part of the application is creating reports (basically excel and pdf files), i would like to add the capability of uploading those files to a sharepoint list, to create kind of a history for our reports and to give the user the opportunity to review old reports.

is it possible to interface Foxpro / Sharepoint? any API available ? I've done a lot of research i found lots of interesting articles in C#, but i have to come up with something written in Foxpro 7 or 9.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint provides a set of web services that you could probably use.

Documented here for SP2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: which one is the best choice for uploading files? I'm not familiar with sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with the somewhat limited environment of FoxPro, there is a possible low tech alternative.  Simply map a network drive to the desired SharePoint library and then save the files in FoxPro to that drive.  Using the SharePoint Web Services is obviously the superior answer (for several reasons) but this might be quicker in a controlled environment.

Comment: i agree, i was thinking of something like, attach an email address to a sharepoint list, send email, and have some internal process at sharepoint that copy attachments...but i will consider your solution if i do not succeed in making it work with emails

Comment: Actually that is an option as well.  Simply email-enable the document library and send an email to it with the file as an attachment.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-HA010082307.aspx#BMdoclib